# Meaning of property of concave/convex functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I dont understand the following property of concave/convex functions

[image]

The main reason is that I don't understand the M_f and M^f notation, which I have never seen before.

Hope someone can help with at least explaining what M_f  and M^f stands for.

Comment: Do you understand the set-builder notation after $f$? That is, do you understand the bit to the right of  
$$
M_f = \{(\mathbf x,y):\mathbf x \in S \text{ and } y \leq f(\mathbf x) \} 
$$

Comment: I dont understand what M_f itself stands for.

Comment: $M_f$ itself stands for the stuff to the right.  So, if you understand that, then you understand what $M_f$ stands for, hence my question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set $M_{f}=\{ (\mathbf x,y): x\in S \text{ and } y\le f(\mathbf x) \}$ is the set of points in $\mathbf x\!-\!y$-plane that are below the graph of the function $f$.

The set $M^f=\{ (\mathbf x,y): x\in S \text{ and } y\ge f(\mathbf x) \}$ is the set of points in $\mathbf x\!-\!y$-plane that are above the graph of the function $f$.

Comment: Note that a bold $\mathbf x$ is usually used to imply that $\mathbf x$ is a vector.

Comment: I've never heard of the "$\mathbf x$-$y$ plane", but I guess it's as good a name as any.

Answer (score 0):

They are *defining the notation* within the statement.  In particular,

> $$M_f = \{(\mathbf x,y):\mathbf x \in S \text{ and } y \leq f(\mathbf x) \}$$

means that $M_f$ is (by definition) the set of all ordered pairs $(\mathbf x,y)$ such that $x \in S \text{ and } y \leq f(\mathbf x)$.  The property of convex functions is that this set is convex if and only if the function is concave.

So, for example: the function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = x^2$ is convex, and equivalently [the region $\{(x,y): y \geq x^2\}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20y%20%3E%3D%20x%5E2) is a convex subset of $\Bbb R^2$.